# Convertir a diccionario una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de obtener un diccionario con claves a partir de una lista de listas.

Lista de listas:

```
users = [['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John'], 
['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis'], 
['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']]
```

Claves:

```
user_keys = ['phoneNumber', 'lastName', 'firstName']
```

Me gustaría obtener lo siguiente:

```
resultado=[{'phoneNumber': '1043100330', 'lastName': 'Smith, 'firstName': 'John'},
        {'phoneNumber': '1043100331', 'lastName': 'Swartz', 'firstName': 'Francis'},
        {'phoneNumber': '1043100332', 'lastName': 'Laff', 'firstName': 'Michael'},
        ]
```

Este es mi codigo en Python3.6:

```
for user in users:
    for i in users:
        d = dict(zip(user_keys, i))

print(d)
```

Pero la salida es:

```
{'phoneNumber': '1043100332', 'lastName': 'Laff', 'firstName': 'Michael'}
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: @ Israel-ICM , gracias hice la traduccion a español. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu estrategia de usar `zip()` para crear el diccionario era correcta, pero te faltaba ir añadiendo cada uno de los diccionarios `d` que vas creando a una lista (y te sobraba uno de los bucles anidados).

Puedes hacerlo en una línea utilizando comprensiones de listas:

```
user_keys = ['phoneNumber', 'lastName', 'firstName']
users = [
  ['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John'], 
  ['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis'], 
  ['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']]

resultado = [ dict(zip(user_keys, i)) for i in users ]
```

Se obtiene así:

```
[{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'phoneNumber': '1043100330'},
 {'firstName': 'Francis', 'lastName': 'Swartz', 'phoneNumber': '1043100331'},
 {'firstName': 'Michael', 'lastName': 'Laff', 'phoneNumber': '1043100332'}]
```

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Nota editada: Transmití mal mi idea. El punto es que mi respuesta no tiene por objetivo reemplazar la respuesta aceptada, si no dar una alternativa que te pueda ayudar a aprender del error y entender la solución.

## Explicación

Tu error se debe a que cada vez que se ejecuta esta linea `d = dict(zip(user_keys, i))` creas un nuevo diccionario y cambias el valor de la variable d al nuevo diccionario. Esto hace que el diccionario anterior se elimine ya que no hay ninguna variable referenciandolo.
Y lo que imprimes en d es el ultimo diccionario que creaste antes de que el bucle for terminase.

Además, no es necesario hacer el for anidado, eso va a hacer que tengas repetidos todos los items tantas veces como items haya en la lista original (si tubieras una lista y estubieras agregando los diccionarios a ella). En tu caso sería 3 veces.

Piensa que tu código hace algo equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']))

d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']))

d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100330', 'Smith', 'John']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100331', 'Swartz', 'Francis']))
d = dict(zip(user_keys, ['1043100332', 'Laff', 'Michael']))

print(d)
```

Lo que quieres lograr es una lista de diccionarios. Para lograr esto primero tienes que crear la lista y luego ir agregando el diccionario creado al final.

## Solución

Puedes aplicar el siguiente método:

```
# Creo una lista vacia donde estarán los diccionarios
resultado = []

# De la lista users obtengo cada sublista y la guardo en la variable user.
for user in users:
    #Agrego el diccionario al final de la lista resultado
    resultado.append(dict(zip(user_keys, user)))

print(resultado)
```

Que tiene un equivalente con [comprension de listas](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/#:%7E:text=La%20comprensi%C3%B3n%20de%20listas%20en,muy%20legible%20y%20funcionalmente%20eficiente.) a esto:

```
resultado = [dict(zip(user_keys, user)) for user in users]
```

Comment: @ Dante S. Excelente! muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Muy buena explicacion.